# Conversion of specifc time to milliseconds using AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk, date

I have a file with data:

```
[15:29:58.496640]
[15:29:58.496644]
[15:29:58.496665]
[15:29:58.496682]
[15:29:58.497096]
[15:29:58.498621]
```

I want the output in milliseconds using `awk` on CentOS.

For example:

```
15:29:58.496640 -> 1499421598.496
```

code tried:

```
awk '{gsub(/[][]/,"");a=$1;x="'"`date -d a +'%s.%3N'`"'"; print x" " a}' file
```

Comment: No, your `awk` isn't doing anything to the date. It's calling an external command, `date` and *that's* what is processing it. I am trying to understand if you need a pure awk solution or if you are OK with using the command `date`.

Comment: @terdon Both will do work fine for me. using date will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes to existing code:

```
day=$(date +%d-%b-%y)
awk -v var=$day 'BEGIN{cmd="date +%s.%6N -d "} {gsub(/[][]/,"");a=varFS$1;cmd a|getline var1;print var1;}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

We can trim the leading and closing brackets with `tr`, and then actually use `awk` to do the math really simply:

```
$ tr -d '[]' < input | awk -F: '{secs=$3; secs+=$2*60; secs+=$1*60*60; printf "%.3f\n", secs*1000 }'
55798496.640
55798496.644
55798496.665
55798496.682
55798497.096
55798498.621
```

To show both the input and the output (with the braces tacked back on), we just expand the `printf` statement:

```
$ tr -d '[]' < input | awk -F: '{secs=$3; secs+=$2*60; secs+=$1*60*60; printf "[%s]\t%.3f\n", $0,secs*1000 }'
[15:29:58.496640]   55798496.640
[15:29:58.496644]   55798496.644
[15:29:58.496665]   55798496.665
[15:29:58.496682]   55798496.682
[15:29:58.497096]   55798497.096
[15:29:58.498621]   55798498.621
```

Answer (score 1):

Without awk some (not very nice) possibility can be to format the seconds with `date` and cut the remaining ms with `sed`:

```bash
$ DATE="15:29:58.498621"
$ echo $(date +%s --date="$DATE" --utc).$(echo $DATE | sed -r "s/.*\.([0-9]{3}).*/\1/g")
1499441398.498
```

Answer (score 0):

With ***shell*** while loop:

```
while read r; do date -d "${r:1:-1}" +%s.%3N ; done < file
```

The output:

```
1499430598.496
1499430598.496
1499430598.496
1499430598.496
1499430598.497
1499430598.498
```